# Heatwave events count in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to count the number of heatwave events for each pixel throughout my time series of land surface temperature. I have a specific definition for a heatwave event: it should last for 5 or more days, and its temperature should be 5 degrees or more higher than the 20-year mean temperature. To achieve this goal, I created an image representing the 20-year mean temperature and an image collection for the timestamps of interest. I then subtracted each image in the collection from the mean image and converted the result to binary. If the difference was 5 or more, I set it to 1; otherwise, I set it to 0. Now, I have a binary time series image collection.

now i have no idea, how to tally the occurrences in which a pixel maintained a value of 1 for 5 or more consecutive days across my entire image collection. My goal is to create a map wherein each pixel signifies the number of heatwave events in that pixel, as per my defined criteria, throughout the entire image collection.

This is my current working script:

```js
// Load the 'countries' dataset from Natural Earth.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0");

// Filter the collection to get the specific country by name (e.g., 'Iraq').
var countryNames = [117];
var country = countries.filter(ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_CODE', countryNames));
// dates 
var startyear = 2001;
var endyear = 2020;


// Make a list with years
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear);

// Load the MODIS land surface temperature dataset.
var modisLST = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filterDate('2001-01-01', '2020-12-31')
  .filterBounds(country)
  .select('LST_Day_1km');
  
var modislstt = modisLST.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'))
print('modislstt',modislstt)
var modcell = modislstt.map(function (img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});
// 20 years mean land surface temperature
var mean20years = modcell.mean().select('LST_Day_1km'); 
print('mean20years',mean20years)


// load modis again 
var modisLSTh = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filterDate('2018-07-20', '2018-07-30')
  .filterBounds(country)
  .select('LST_Day_1km');
  
var modislsttt = modisLSTh.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'))
print('modislsttt',modislsttt)
var modcelll = modislsttt.map(function (img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});

  
  // Calculate the difference between each image in 'modisLSTh' and the 20-year mean image.
var diffCollection = modcelll.map(function(image) {
  // Subtract the 20-year mean image from the current image.
  var diffImage = image.subtract(mean20years);

  // Return the difference image with the same date and other metadata.
  return diffImage.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

print('diffCollection',diffCollection)


// Define a threshold value (5 in this case) for classification
var threshold = 5;


// Define a function to classify pixels based on the threshold
var classifyPixels = function(image) {
  // Create a binary mask where pixels >= threshold are 1, and all others are 0
  var binaryMask = image.gte(threshold);
  
  // Apply the binary mask and set masked pixels to 0
  var classifiedImage = binaryMask.unmask(0);

  // Return the classified image
  return image.addBands(classifiedImage.rename('classified'));
};

// Apply the classifyPixels function to each image in the diffCollection
var binaryImageCollection = diffCollection.map(classifyPixels).select("classified");

// Set masked pixels in the binaryImageCollection to 0
var binaryImageCollection = binaryImageCollection.map(function(image) {
  return image.unmask(0);
});

var clippedBinaryImageCollection = binaryImageCollection.map(function(image) {
  return image.clip(country.geometry());
});

print('clippedBinaryImageCollection',clippedBinaryImageCollection);
```

Comment: What is the problem? does your code not work? if so, does it raise an error? where? does it not do what you want? If you provide a code attempt you need to tell us what the problem with it is. if it is to provide context, then it should be clearer.